# Thymeleaf check if array contains string

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to check if an array contains a certain string and render based if its there or not.

testResponse.test1.itemTypes = ['here', 'nothere']

```
<div th:if="${testResponse!= null AND testResponse.test1.itemTypes == 'here'}">
<ul>
    <li><span>I'm here</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Thymeleaf `#arrays.contains()` expression - see the documentation [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#arrays).

So, for your example it would be:

```
<div th:if="${testResponse != null 
       and #arrays.contains(testResponse.test1.itemTypes, 'here')}">
    <ul>
        <li><span>I'm here</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that the `and` has to be lower case. `AND` is not valid Thymeleaf syntax.

**UPDATE:**

For the additional case mentioned in comments, use the `not` operator as follows:

```
<div th:if="${testResponse != null 
       and not #arrays.contains(testResponse.test1.itemTypes, 'here')}">
    <ul>
        <li><span>I'm missing</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: and to test if it doesn't contain that string would i do #arrays.!contains(testResponse.test1.itemTypes, 'here')?

Comment: Answer updated. You can see an overview of the core operators and expressions [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax).